# Which static control was pressed STN_CLICKED?

Tags: winapi

I have multiple static controls, defined with the `SS_NOTIFY` style.

How can I discern which control was clicked when I am handling the message with STN_CLICKED?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need assign unique ID to every control. and you got this id back inside `wParam` when you handle [`STN_CLICKED`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/stn-clicked) notification

for example

```
switch (uMsg)
{
case WM_COMMAND:
    switch (wParam)
    {
    case MAKEWPARAM(IDC_STATIC_1, STN_CLICKED ):
        do_something_1();
        break;
    case MAKEWPARAM(IDC_STATIC_2, STN_CLICKED ):
        do_something_2();
        break;
    }
    break;
}
```

Comment: You should not be using `MAKEWPARAM()` in this manner.  Use `LOWORD()` and `HIWORD()` on the `wParam` instead, eg: `if (HIWORD(wParam) == STN_CLICKED) { switch (LOWORD(wParam)) { case IDC_STATIC_1: ... case IDC_STATIC_2: ... } }`

Comment: @RemyLebeau - why ? what is wrong with this ?

Comment: What you have shown will "work", but `WM_COMMAND` is used by a lot of different controls, so why make the compiler process the `switch` for unrelated controls? You should always check the notification code first, then process the remaining values accordingly as needed.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - we can use both variants. in some case better your. in some case better my. no general answer. depend from concrete window(dialog) procedure logic. and in any case different will be very minimal (not visible at all) by binary code and performance. this is faster question of coding style

Comment: @RemyLebeau *compiler process the switch for unrelated controls* really count of windows messages which receive  window procedure not depend from how we write it. in any case we receive the same `WM_COMMAND` count. my switch in most case will be more fast - we just compare wParam for several values (compile time constants). in usual code (like you want use) we need first split wParam to 2 value. switch by one value. then again switch by another. not think that this will be better

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/stn-clicked) tells you:

> `lParam`: Handle to the static control.

The `lParam` has the `HWND` of the static control that is sending the notification.

Comment: more useful here use `wParam` - `switch( wParam) { case MAKEWPARAM(IDC_STATIC_N, STN_CLICKED ):...}` because identifier of the static control known in compile time - we assign it by self, when use HWND of control usually not comfortable

Comment: @rbm By default, the dialog resource editor assigns `IDC_STATIC` (-1) to *all* static controls. The OP clearly wants to discern which specific STATIC control was clicked. The `HWND` passed through `lParam` is the unique identifier, regardless of the control ID assigned.

Comment: *By default* - need change this default, if we want handle click on static control (by default we not handle notifications from static).

Comment: @rbm The OP wants to call `InvalidateRect`, so they need the handle anyway. There's no apparent reason to complicate things.

Comment: if call `InvalidateRect` only - yes have hwnd of control (lParam) is ok. however if we do different actions on different static click - we anyway need different id - how do we distinguish to which control belong hwnd ? and i search for `InvalidateRect` word on this page - and found it only in your comment first. not understand why you decide that OP want call `InvalidateRect` ? and only this

Comment: *How can I discern which control was clicked when I am handling the message* - how you can do this with hwnd of control ? we can and need use hwnd for send message to control for example. but for discern which control - need assign different id to controls and use it

Comment: A child window's `HWND` is *always* unique given any particular parent window. A child window's ID is not. I'm sure you know how to store pointer-sized values and compare pointer-sized values.

Comment: yes, hwnd is unique, **but** - how you will use it for *discern which control was clicked* ?  really how ? and in what problem use unique id for every control ?

Comment: Let me repeat myself: *"A child window's `HWND` is always unique given any particular parent window. A child window's ID is not. I'm sure you know how to store pointer-sized values and compare pointer-sized values."* Comparing pointer-sized values for equality establishes whether you're looking at the control you are interested in or not. Some will call this a no-brainer.

Comment: compare with what ?  how you can know to which static control belong hwnd ? this is unique value but it nothing say about - to which control it belong. i propose clear and simply solituon - use control id

Comment: Why don't you entertain us with your proposed answer then?

Comment: ok, if you want